# how to retrieve the model id after successful payment in paypal - laravel

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

i am using express checkout with this package :

```
https://github.com/srmklive/laravel-paypal
```

exactly as example repository one change i made is that the price and item info was hard coded but i passed a model to that function called event because i want to sell events . so it looks like below now :

```
protected function getCheckoutData($recurring = false,$event = null)
    {
        $data = [];

        $order_id = Invoice::all()->count() + 1;

        if ($recurring === true) {
            $data['items'] = [
                [
                    'name'  => 'Monthly Subscription '.config('paypal.invoice_prefix').' #'.$order_id,
                    'price' => 12222,
                    'qty'   => 1,
                ],
            ];

            $data['return_url'] = url('/paypal/ec-checkout-success?mode=recurring');
            $data['subscription_desc'] = 'Monthly Subscription '.config('paypal.invoice_prefix').' #'.$order_id;
        } else {
            $data['items'] = [
                [
                    'name'  => $event->title,
                    'price' => $event->price,
                    'qty'   => 1,
                    'event_id'   => $event->id,
                ]
            ];

            $data['return_url'] = url('/paypal/ec-checkout-success');
        }

        $data['invoice_id'] = config('paypal.invoice_prefix').'_'.$order_id;
        $data['invoice_description'] = $event->title;
        $data['cancel_url'] = url('/');

        $total = 0;
        foreach ($data['items'] as $item) {
            $total += $item['price'] * $item['qty'];
        }

        $data['total'] = $total;

        return $data;
    }
```

now on `getExpressCheckoutSuccess` function after payment it calls the `getCheckoutData` again but this time there is no model event on that like below :

```
  public function getExpressCheckoutSuccess(Request $request)
    {
        $recurring = ($request->get('mode') === 'recurring') ? true : false;
        $token = $request->get('token');
        $PayerID = $request->get('PayerID');

        $cart = $this->getCheckoutData($recurring);

        // Verify Express Checkout Token
        $response = $this->provider->getExpressCheckoutDetails($token);
. 
.
.
```

so my question is that how can pass the paypal my event id and it returns that to me again or do some thing to detect the event
and pass it to getCheckoutData and verify the payment . thanks in advance

Comment: Given `function getCheckoutData($recurring = false,$event = null)` and `$cart = $this->getCheckoutData($recurring);` Why would you expect `$event` to be populated if you aren't passing it?

Comment: @miken32 thats exactly what i want i want this model in my return from paypal so is there any way to send any extra data to payapl and recive them back on success payment ?